# Sticky footer, but with a twist

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

So, I already know how to make a sticky footer, primarily using this method:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

That said, I'm trying something a little different:

Currently, I am trying to have all of my website's content stick to the bottom of the page, but right on top of the footer, so it looks something like:

---

Header

---

blank space (this gap closes as more content is added)

|

|

|

|

|

---

Content (sticks to top of footer)

---

Footer (sticks to bottom of page)

---

As more content is added, the content rises UP, towards the header, while the footer sticks to the bottom. Simple enough.

What I'm trying to figure out is, how can I make it so that once the content has filled up enough to reach the top of page (and hit the bottom of the header), to THEN begin pushing the footer off of the bottom of the screen.

As far as code, I really don't know where to begin, though I'd like to avoid scripts and keep it pure CSS if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to accomplish this with CSS alone, as CSS does not compare variables outside of media queries and this is not a place where media queries can help; however, the jQuery solution is quite simple. Just run a function like this every time the content changes:

```
function addSomethingToContent(){

    var cHeight = parseInt($("#content").height());
    var hHeight = parseInt($("#header").height());
    var fHeight = parseInt($("#footer").height());
    var wHeight = parseInt($(window).height());

    if((cHeight + hHeight + fHeight) > wHeight)
    {
        $("#footer").css({
            "bottom": (wHeight - (cHeight + hHeight + fHeight)) + "px"
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#footer").css("bottom", "0px");
    }

}
```

Assuming your footer is positioned absolutely to the bottom of the page using the `bottom` property in CSS, this will slide the footer down by the difference of the sum of the heights and the window height.

Comment: Does this work if the header and footer heights are set dynamically? (i.e. height defined by the amount of content within the divs, not by the CSS)

Comment: @user3183717 Yes. [`.height()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fheight%2F&ei=I0hYU8XFBoSLyAS-iYHoAQ&usg=AFQjCNHultDjg27j4qzC2XJ7II4KcfHN1g&bvm=bv.65397613,d.aWw) returns the rendered height, not the CSS height. CSS height can be retrieved with `parseInt($(elm).css("height"));`